# How to make UITextView background transparent?

Tags: iphone, xcode, background, uitextview

In my application, I have a large text field that allows the user to input notes, but the only issue is that it does not blend into the background image that I have set. With the UITextField, you can set the border in the Interface Builder so that it does not have a white background, it has a transparent background making it show the background I have set behind it. I did not see this Border option with the UITextView, does anyone know how I can achieve the same effect? (I'm using Xcode 4.2 by the way).

Thank you!

Comment: 'Border width' and 'Border color' are better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the opacity of the background in Interface Builder.

[image: Text View with background]

[image: Select it and change the background colour]

[image: Slide the opacity slider to make the background transparent.]

Comment: Thanks you so much, that helped out tremendously!

Comment: Not a problem! Glad I helped!

Answer (score 3):

You can use following code-

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

....


textView.layer.borderWidth = 5.0f;
textView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor grayColor] CGColor];
```

decide color and border width as per your need.

Answer (score 2):

To set the background to be transparent on a UITextView you can use

```
UITextView* myTextView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,280,180)];
[myTextView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

If you want to add a border to the UITextView then you would need to add that to the layer of the textView which you could do in the following way

```
[[myTextView layer] setCornerRadius:15.0f]; //You don't need to set this but it will give the view rounded corners.
[[myTextView layer] setBorderWidth:1.0f]; //again you pick the value 1 is quite a thin border
[[myTextView layer] setBorderColor:[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]]; //again you can choose the color.
```

That should answer both your questions I think.