# Can the border of UITextView or UILabel be set in Storyboard?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, interface-builder, storyboard

I want to set the border of a `UITextView` or a `UILabel` in a Storyboard.
Can it be done?

Programmatically, it is `setBorderColor` and `setBorderWidth`.

But can the border be set in a Storyboard?

Comment: Please checkout these links : -

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8716446/uitextview-issue

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9392219/outline-to-uilabel-text

Answer (score 69, accepted):

As was previously pointed out, these properties are part of a layer, not part of a view. But you can still set their values in IB. As hypercrypt pointed out, you can use User Defined Runtime Attributes. Since all views have a "layer" property,  you can set "layer.borderWidth" for instance.

Here's a case, where I'm changing the cornerRadius. Works great.

[image]

Comment: OK. addendum. You cannot set the borderColor this way. But you can set the borderWidth (and cornerRadius). Don't know why this is, unfortunately. Perhaps when you set a color as an attribute, it's looking for a UIColor, but CALayer wants a CGColor?

Comment: This worked.  And layer.cornerRadius DID ALSO WORK ok. I'm using xcode 4.6.2 and tested it on iPhone 5 and simulator.

Comment: @DanMorrow Yep, when you set a User Defined Runtime Attribute as type 'Color', it means a `UIColor`, not a `CGColor`. You can still get the behavior you want (being able to set border color from Interface Builder), but you'll need a custom `UIView` subclass with a `UIColor` property that you set from the storyboard and code that applies that color to the border, and then you'll need to nest your views in the storyboard inside instances of that subclass. Whether this is more hassle than it's worth is left as a question for the reader.

Comment: @MarkAmery Actually you don't *need* to subclass `UIView`, you can also accomplish this functionality with a category.  Define a `UIColor` property in the category interface, implement the setter that sets `self.layer.borderColor = inputColor.CGColor`, and implement the getter to return `[UIColor colorWithCGColor:self.layer.borderColor]`.

Comment: and building on @dmur , you can now use IBDesignable, to actually draw what it looks like in Xcode 6. Check it out: http://nshipster.com/ibinspectable-ibdesignable/

Answer (score 7):

use simple code in .m,it show border in view

```
view.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0f;
view.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
view.layer.borderWidth = .5f;
view.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor orangeColor].CGColor;
view.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.4;
view.layer.shadowRadius = 5.0f;
```

Comment: the question is how to do that in storyboard.

Comment: I know this is an old topic but it came up in MY search, so the solution here is to set the User Defined Runtime Attribute "layer.borderWidth" to a numeric value (in points, so 0.5 would be 1/2 point)

Answer (score 4):

If you're targeting iOS 6+ you can use the *User Defined Runtime Attributes* in the *Identity Inspector* to set any properties. Performance is not an issue for either, so it doesn't matter.